# Need help in trying to write a procedure for this in scheme

Tags: scheme, procedure

I am working on a tough word problem that's written down below, and i need some help in trying to figure out how to approach this:

Suppose you have a Scheme function that counts the number of people picked up by a certain 
bus at a given stop. The bus has many stops, each of which is assigned a number between 1 and 
100.
Write a Scheme procedure that takes in (i) a function f, that gives the 
number of people picked up from each bus stop, and (ii) an integer m, and returns the number of 
stops at which the bus picked up m or fewer people.
Example: suppose the bus stop pickup function is as follows:

```
(define (stops n)
    (cond ((= n 10) 20)
          ((= n 18) 18)
          ((= n 39) 52)
          ((= n 52) 12)
          ((= n 58) 23)
          ((= n 70) 34)
          ((= n 73) 18)
          ((= n 82) 11)
          ((= n 97) 33)
          (else 0)))
```

When the procedure is applied to the stops procedure above and given m=20, it should return 5 
because the only stops where there were 20 or fewer passengers picked up were stops 10, 18, 52, 
73, and 82.

My first approach to this would be to write a helper function to add the parameter n, though I'm not entirely sure what it would do (add the count, maybe?). Other than that, i'm completely stuck. If i could have some clarification. guidance, or direction to this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to write a function that takes as arguments a procedure `f` and a number `m`.  You need to call `f` with each number `i` from `1` to `100`, and count how many times `(f i)` is less than or equal to `m`.

Comment: Could you maybe explain a little more? I'm still having trouble with the logic of it all

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of named lets, so there:

```
(define (how-many f m)
  (let loop ((i 1) (res 0))
    (if (<= i 100)
        (loop (+ i 1) (if (<= 1 (f i) m) (+ res 1) res))
        res)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Racket-only solution:

```
(define (count-fewer-or-equal f m)
  (count (lambda (i) (<= 1 (f i) m))
         (range 1 100)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement iteration using recursion.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
(define (count f m)
  (define (count-iter i sum)
    (if (> i 100)
        sum
        (count-iter (+ i 1)
                    (if (include-stop? i)
                        (+ sum 1)
                        sum))))
  (count-iter 1 0))
```

Comment: FYI: This is idiomatically written as `(let count-iter ((i 1) (sum 0)) ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Once solution, but far from the only one

?b being my notation for a predicate that returns 0 or 1 instead of #t or #f.

```
(define *potential-stops* (iota 100 1 1))

(define (stops-lt-m f m)
  (let ((lt-m?b (lambda (x) (if (> (f x) m) 0 1))))
    (reduce + 0 (map lt-m?b potential-stops))))
```

Could also use a (length (filter ...)) implementation with a lt-m?

*potential-stops* because it's a constant but could need to be changed if the stop numbering system changed.